# Android fragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I got an error reported from a user the other day, but how it happened is boggling my mind.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.inthub.greenfly/com.inthub.greenfly.view.fragment.MyProfileFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.inthub.greenfly.view.fragment.MyProfileFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.inthub.greenfly.view.fragment.MyProfileFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I know your first thought is "you must be starting up the fragment with startActivity or something". I start up this fragment in one single place:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragment, new MyProfileFragment());
                    ft.commit();
```

I have been unable to figure out how this was started as an activity and also have not been able to reproduce it. Any ideas where to continue looking?

My class extends Fragment and not FragmentActivity.

I have an onCreate, I've removed a little of the code to keep things short:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getActivity().getActionBar() != null) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.myprofile);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_profile, container, false);

        .... tons of lines setting up my view ....
    }
```

I am declaring my fragments in the manifest file as activities. I am reading that it may be incorrect to do this. If that is the source of the problem why am I unable to reproduce the error across multiple devices?

```
<activity
   android:name="com.inthub.greenfly.view.fragment.MyProfileFragment"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

Update, just to be clear. I have had the incorrect activity lines in my manifest for quite some time and have never encountered this error. It was reported through Crashlytics from another user. I have spent hundreds of hours developing and testing across multiple devices and not encountered it. If it is as simple as removing the lines, why am I unable to reproduce it?

Comment: Could you post full code of `MyProfileFragment`?

Comment: The error isn't in that code fragment, I don't think. You'd need to show us `MyProfileFramgnet`, or at least the `onCreate` part of it.

Comment: is your activity extended FragmentActivity ?

Comment: extends Fragment and not FragmentActivity. I'll update my post with some more snippets.

Comment: Sounds cool!! Must sure that by mistake you didn't add `MyProfileFragment` as a Activity in your manifest file.

Comment: I do have my fragment listed as an activity in my manifest, along with five or six others. If this is the reason why am I unable to recreate the error on any of my devices?